# DB2 Select Query with data in file

Tags: file, select, csv, db2, external

Lets say I have a csv file(ids.csv) with ids like

```
101,102,103......1MILLION
```

I wanted to select data from the table by reading ids from file in the where clause

Something like

```
select * from employee where id in (<I wanted to read ids from external csv file>)
```

Is this possible in any database. I am interested in db2.

Due to limitation in character length in sql if i put all these ids in in clause its not allowing to run a query. Right now I am chunking ids in to smaller set and running the query.

Answer (score 1):

Import the data into a table using the [DB2 IMPORT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0008304.htm) command.

It will be something like:

```
db2 import from ids.csv of del create into id_table
```

You can read more about the command at the above link.

Once that's done it's a simple matter of:

```
select * from employee where id in (select id from id_table)
```

Comment: Depending on your platform, you may find that an `inner join` performs better - there has been some indication that older versions may turn the `where x in` into a correlated subquery.  Otherwise, yes, importing it into a temp table is the way to go.